# Can you KVO the property gestureRecognizers on a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, key-value-observing

I am creating a `UIView` that can alter the `gestureRecognizers` that are added to itself. Just to test it out I am adding a tap gesture right after adding the observer to trigger the KVO.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"gestureRecognizers" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:observeContext];
    [super awakeFromNib];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(test)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [self createCircles];
}


- (void)test
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"got tapped");
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"something got in here");
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"gestureRecognizers"]) {
        DDLogVerbose(@"ThreeCirclesView got a gesture recognizer");
    }
}
```

However, it's not working. Am I doing this right? Or is the property `gestureRecognizers` not KVO-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most of Apple's properties, I think that gestureRecognizers is not observable. However, you can override addGestureRecognizer: in your UIView subclass so you can respond to the addition,

```
-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    NSLog(@"added a gr");
    // do whatever in ressponse to a new gesture recognizer being added
}
```

You can do the same with removeGestureRecognizer: if you need to look at removal also.

Comment: How can one tell if a property is observable for KVO?

Comment: @RantriX, the only way I know is to try to observe it and see if it works.